# when collection is converted to json, query property have weird schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, postman-collection

I have tried 2 ways to do this both resulted in same

#### Directly manipulating url

```
    const request = new Request({
      header: requestHeader,
      url: `${apiEndpoint}?${new URLSearchParams(params).toString()}}`,
      method: 'GET',
      auth: null,
    });
```

#### using `QueryParam`

```
    Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
      const queryParams = new QueryParam({
        key,
        value: params[key],
      });
      request.addQueryParams(queryParams);
    });
```

both result into query property like this

```
"query": [
    {
        "key": "members",
        "value": {
            "prop1": {
                "key": "keyName",
                "value": "VALUE"
            },
            "prop2": {
                "key": "keyName2",
                "value": "VALUE2"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "reference",
        "value": {
            "prop1": {
                "key": "keyName",
                "value": "VALUE"
            },
            "prop2": {
                "key": "keyName2",
                "value": "VALUE2"
            },
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "Type",
        "value": {
            "_postman_propertyName": "QueryParam",
            "_postman_propertyIndexKey": "key",
            "_postman_propertyAllowsMultipleValues": true
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "_postman_listIndexKey",
        "value": "key"
    },
    {
        "key": "_postman_listAllowsMultipleValues",
        "value": true
    }
],
```

when this data is imported into postman it results in this url
`{{url}}?members&reference&Type&_postman_listIndexKey=key&_postman_listAllowsMultipleValues`

I cross checked by exporting postman collection and there query is array of objects

```
{
    "key": "KEY1",
    "value": "VALUE1"
},
{
    "key": "KEY2",
    "value": "VALUE2"
},
```

This happens when using `collection.toJSON()`, when `request.toJSON()` is used it in expected format.